Bluem Payment - Verify Signature for webhook
I'm buiding a system using PHP and Codeigniter 4. We are using Bluem as our payment gateway. They have provided us with the .crt file. They are providing Signature string in their webhook. So I'm confused on How to verify the signature with the .crt file using PHP and CodeIgniter 4?
Thanks
Need to verify that whether the given sigature is matching with the .crt or not?

What have you actually tried? Where are you stuck? [ask]

I haven't tried anything. Because I've no idea on how to verify the signature with .crt files?

Did you take the time to request the documentation?

Yes I do, but they have provided me with the Java code.

https://github.com/bluem-development/bluem-php

Under the hood, they are using a .pem file but I have a .crt file. https://github.com/bluem-development/bluem-php/tree/master/keys

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Might want to check How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?
